# My opengl texture is rendering as a green background

Tags: java, opengl, textures

I am trying to render a texture of a Minecraft creeper on to a rectangle in openGL, but the texture ends up looking like this(the texture is supposed to be where the green background is.)
[image: emphasized text]

I noticed that the picture I am trying to display has a outline that match's the color of the green box in the middle of the game.

I also noticed that when I change the picture to a image with white edges I get I white box where the texture should be.

This makes me think that the program is rendering the outline of the images for some reason.

[image: picture of the problem]

Here some of my code:

Vertex Shader:

```
#version 400 core
in vec3 pos;
in vec2 textCoords;

out vec2 textCoordsPass;

void main(void){
    gl_Position = vec4(pos,1.0);
    textCoordsPass = textCoords;
}
```

Fragment Shader:

```
#version 400 core

in vec2 textCoordsPass;

out vec4 outC;

uniform sampler2D uni;
void main(void){
     outC = texture(uni,textCoordsPass);

}
```

Here is some of the shader code:

```
vertexShaderID = loadShader(vertexFile,GL20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
fragmentShaderID = loadShader(fragmentFile,GL20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
programID = GL20.glCreateProgram();
GL20.glAttachShader(programID, vertexShaderID);
GL20.glAttachShader(programID, fragmentShaderID);
bindAttributes();
GL20.glLinkProgram(programID);
GL20.glValidateProgram(programID);
```

Main game loop:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    DisplaySetup.createDisplay();
    float[] vertices = {  -0.5f, 0.5f, 0,
              -0.5f, -0.5f, 0,
              0.5f, -0.5f, 0,
              0.5f, 0.5f, 0f};
    int indices[] = {0,1,3,3,1,2};
    Loader load = new Loader();
    RawModel Model = load.loadToVAO(vertices, indices);
    Render render = new Render();
    staticShader shader = new staticShader();
    ModelTexture Creeper = new ModelTexture(load.loadTexture("u"));
    TexturedModel TextModel = new TexturedModel(Model, Creeper);

    while(!Display.isCloseRequested()){
        render.prepare();
        shader.start();
        render.render(TextModel);
        shader.stop();






        DisplaySetup.updateDisplay();
    }
    shader.cleanUP();
    load.clean();




}
```

I am not sure if this will be enough code so tell me if you think more is needed.

I know that there are a lot of questions on a similar topic but, they did seem to help me too muchI am a opengl noob so do not be to harsh

Comment: You are only setting up vertex positions, but no texture coordinates. Unless you bind something to the `textCoords` attribute it will be (0,0) for all vertices.

Comment: what part of the code are you referring to. Sorry I am an OpenGL noob

Comment: You have a shader variable called `textCoords` and you assume that it contains some texture coordinates. But you never specify where the data should come from.

Comment: Your `vertices`. It only includes the positions there's no texture coordinates.